# Can I subclass class definition code in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Basically, I want to do something like:

```
class Animal
  @type: 'animal'
  console.log "#{ @type } type defined"

class Dog extends Animal
  @type: 'dog'
  ...???...
```

such that when these two classes are **loaded**, the console output looks like

```
animal type defined
dog type defined
```

FWIW, the first line is logged; the second is where I'm having issues.

I've tried playing with `__super__` and whatnot but those reference the constructor.  I'm trying to get to the superclasses function definition itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your log message on class loading (function definition), you cannot use inheritance (with calling super constructor or something). Just write

```
class Animal
  @type: 'animal'
  console.log "#{ @type } type defined"

class Dog extends Animal
  @type: 'dog'
  console.log "#{ @type } type defined"
```

Comment: well -- the *need* is to run boilerplate code on definition of all subclasses of a class.  The actual use is much more extensive than I've laid out here.  I'd like to avoid replicating what is represented by the console.log call here...  no way?

Comment: Could you show us that boilderplate code? It sounds to me like it should be an independent static function which is called from the class definitions.

Comment: ok, I can live with that approach... thanks for the feedback!